# Django template is not displaying

Tags: django, django-templates

Assuming my model contains data, I have myapp/views.py:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import History
import datetime

def live_view(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    plays_list = History.objects.filter(date=datetime.date(2016,04,22))
    context_list = {'plays':plays_list}
    return render(request,'live.html',context_list)
```

myapp/templates/live.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for key, value in context_list.items %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

myapp/urls.py:

```
from myapp.views import live_view

urlpatterns = [url(r'^live/$', live_view, name="live"),]
```

The output is a page that renders only the base.html template, with no content in the body. What's wrong with my view function or template rendering? Should I be inheriting from TemplateView?

Comment: If you print plays_list, is it definitely not empty?

Comment: yes, plays_list prints out, and is of the form {'plays': [<queryset record>, <queryset record>, <queryset record>]}

Comment: Did you declared `{% block content %} {% endblock %}` in your `base.html`?

Comment: Can you add your base.html as well?

Comment: Try `{% for play in plays %}`

Comment: {% for play in plays %}{{ play.date }}{% endfor %} displays the date field! Why could I not access the dict in the template? I don't understand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass anything called `context_list` to the template. What you pass is the *contents* of that dict, which in this case is just `plays`.

Comment: and @trantu thanks - I believe I had been passing the context_list instance to the template, rather than the contents of the instance.

Comment: @DNburtonguster How did it fixed finally??